# Updating value in for loop / Reseting a for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm working on my first school project so I don't have much experience in doing such web applications, that's why I decided to ask here.

How can I update the value in the for loop syntax or reset it entirely, so it iterates again, like I just reloaded it? I have another function that I decided not to show, simply because it would be useless to. What it does in the end is increments the `taskCount.length` by one. This part technically works but problem is, the function I'm going to show you now, once iterated, will always keep the default `taskCount.length` value, once the page is loaded, it never changes there. Is there any way I can update it?

Here's an example: The function above makes `taskCount.length = '5'` but when the page started it was `taskCount.length = 4`, and when I do `alert(taskCount.length)` from the console, I get 5. But the for loop doesn't want to change.

```
for (var i = 0; i < taskCount.length; i++) {    
            document.getElementsByClassName('task')[i].addEventListener('click', ((j) => {         
                return function() {
                    var shadow = document.createElement('div');
                    // Styling
                    var changingWindow = document.createElement('div');
                    // Styling
                    var changingTitle = document.createElement('p');
                    // Styling
                    var changingText = document.createElement('p');
                    // Styling
                    var changingTitleNode = document.createTextNode('Промяна');
                    var changingTextNode = document.createTextNode('Моля, изберете действие.');
                    var deleteTask = document.createElement('button');
                    var goUp = document.createElement('button');
                    var goDown = document.createElement('button');
                    var unchange = document.createElement('button');
                    // Styling
                    var deleteElementNode = document.createTextNode('Премахни задачата');
                    var goUpNode = document.createTextNode('Премести нагоре');
                    var goDownNode = document.createTextNode('Премести надолу');
                    var unchangeNode = document.createTextNode('Отказ');
                    var justBreak = document.createElement('br');
                    var justBreakAgain = document.createElement('br');
                    var justBreakOneMoreTime = document.createElement('br');
                    body.appendChild(shadow);
                    shadow.appendChild(changingWindow);
                    changingWindow.appendChild(changingTitle);
                    changingTitle.appendChild(changingTitleNode);
                    changingWindow.appendChild(changingText);
                    changingText.appendChild(changingTextNode);
                    changingWindow.appendChild(deleteTask);
                    deleteTask.appendChild(deleteElementNode);
                    deleteTask.onclick = function() {
                        document.getElementsByClassName('task')[j].parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementsByClassName('task')[j]);
                        shadow.parentNode.removeChild(shadow);
                        localStorage.setItem("listContent", document.getElementById('list').innerHTML);
                    }
                    changingWindow.appendChild(justBreak);
                    changingWindow.appendChild(goUp);
                    goUp.appendChild(goUpNode);
                    goUp.onclick = function() {
                        if (j !== 0) {
                            var saveThisTaskValue = document.getElementsByClassName('task')[j].innerHTML;
                            var savePreviousTaskValue = document.getElementsByClassName('task')[j - 1].innerHTML;
                            document.getElementsByClassName('task')[j].innerHTML = savePreviousTaskValue;
                            document.getElementsByClassName('task')[j - 1].innerHTML = saveThisTaskValue;
                        }
                        shadow.parentNode.removeChild(shadow);
                        localStorage.setItem("listContent", document.getElementById('list').innerHTML);
                    }
                    changingWindow.appendChild(justBreakAgain);
                    changingWindow.appendChild(goDown);
                    goDown.appendChild(goDownNode);
                    goDown.onclick = function() {
                        if (j !== document.getElementsByClassName('task').length - 1) {
                            var saveThisTaskValue = document.getElementsByClassName('task')[j].innerHTML;
                            var saveNextTaskValue = document.getElementsByClassName('task')[j + 1].innerHTML;
                            document.getElementsByClassName('task')[j].innerHTML = saveNextTaskValue;
                            document.getElementsByClassName('task')[j + 1].innerHTML = saveThisTaskValue;
                        }
                        shadow.parentNode.removeChild(shadow);
                        localStorage.setItem("listContent", document.getElementById('list').innerHTML);
                    }
                    changingWindow.appendChild(justBreakOneMoreTime);
                    changingWindow.appendChild(unchange);
                    unchange.appendChild(unchangeNode);
                    unchange.onclick = function() {
                        shadow.parentNode.removeChild(shadow);
                    }
                }
            })(i))
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of the page reloading, you can always save the value as a cookie and reuse it again and again. You can update it whenever you want.

Comment: It's supposed to be something like a to-do list for a school project and that's exactly what I'm doing; I'm using localStorage but I'm still looking for another solution just in case.

Comment: If you are can define a global variable on the starting of the page and just use it all over the page, you don't have to reload every time. Like define the variable "var taskCount;" in the starting of the page and use it anywhere.

Comment: It's stored like `var taskCount = document.getElementsByClassName('task');`

Comment: And that's why it's changing with the element changes of the class every time. You can store it in another variable and then it will not change.

Comment: I tried to remove the declaration of the variable and instead of writing `taskCount.length...`, I replaced it with `document.getElementsByClassName('task').length...`. Still not working... I guess I'll stick to `location.reload()` for now.

Comment: No! that's not I have told! just store the count in another variable after  var taskCount = document.getElementsByClassName('task'); and use that one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand you question, but maybe some recursion is what you need. Something along the lines of:

```js
loop(5);

function loop(xTimes) {

   for (var i = 0; i < xTimes; i++) {

        if (newXTimes !== xTimes) {

            loop(newXtimes);
            break;
        }
   }

}
```

Maybe set `newxTimes` as a global variable that can be accessed inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone "from the future" reads this question and it doesn't have any answers, I came up with the solution to reload the page everytime you change the value. Still, I'd like to do it without reloading.